# My newly registered user can login to my django web app

Tags: python, django, authentication, registration

I am new to the community. I usually am able to just find my answer, but I have been searching and searching, and can't seem to find anything similar to what I've got going on. I have a ModelForm set up to register new users. I got it to work, and send information over to the sqlite database. However, when I try to log the newly registered user in it says:

["Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ9cK.png)

login.html:

```html
{% extends 'app/register.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

<a href="{% url 'index' %}">Back to Homepage</a>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Reset password</a>
<br>
<a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpRequest
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from . import forms
from django.contrib import auth

def index(request):
    """Renders the home page."""
    assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
    return render(
        request,
        'app/index.html',
        {
            'title':'Home Page',
            'year':datetime.now().year,
        }
    )
    
def register(request):
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = forms.Registration(request.GET)
        return render(
        request, "app/register.html",
        {"form": form}
        )
    elif request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.Registration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect(reverse("index"))
```

models.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Patient(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    #birthdate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    allergies = models.TextField(blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_login = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and forms.py:

```py
from django import forms
from . import models
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Registration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Patient
        fields = ('first_name','last_name', 'gender', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'allergies',)
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Please forgive me if I've left something out, just let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Please upload whole views.py

Comment: Forms.py and models.py are allright. If there would be any problem, probably it must have popped on the console as well as in your website

Comment: The console doesn't show any issues. Also, if I login as a superuser, it works. Or any type  of user added via django-admin, it works no problem. But trying to login with someone registered through the site (even the the db has all their info stored) doesn't work. I've now updated my post to include my other view. Thanks.

Comment: That is what i said. Problem must be in views.py not on other files. this seems a logical error

Comment: So what do you think I should do? Do I need to make a new view?

Comment: Your model `Patient` is just a normal model. You should user the `User` model for authentication purposes or extend `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` if you want to customize them.

Comment: Ohhhh very interesting... I’m curious if that will fix my issue, I’ll try it tonight thank you!

Comment: I changed it to User model and it still is the same story... Hmm...

Comment: Are there any other suggestions? I have no clue what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of trial and error and fiddling, I ultimately fixed it this way, thanks to Abdul Aziz Barkat's suggestion above.

I changed Patient(models.Model) to Patient(AbstractUser)

And then I also had to change the Registration(forms.ModelForm) to Registration(UserCreationForm). All of the users are authenticating just fine now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In line 33 in the views file you used *auth_login()* function but I could not find where you imported it
did you mean *authentication()* or *login()* functions?